# IBM App Connect Enterprise - HTTPAsynchronous Request, Issue in Correlating Request/Response

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to call a single REST service multiple times with different path parameters, aggregate the responses and send it back as single combined response (kind of an small orchestration). I'm using the group nodes in the App Connect ACE 11. I followed this [blog](https://prasadvadnala.blogspot.com/p/group-nodes-in-ace.html?spref=bl) to develop the flow,
only difference being I'm using a loop

```
WHILE I <= 3 DO
    SET OutputLocalEnvironment = InputLocalEnvironment;
    SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = 'http://10.18.50.64:7004/irf-test-web/api/v1.0.0/party/dfccLoanInfo/' || Environment.Variables.loanIds[I];
    SET I = I + 1;
    PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out';
END WHILE;
```

to call a asynchronous request node. But I'm getting an error saying

```
Jul  1 14:50:33 testesb ACE[25140]: IBM App Connect Enterprise v11008 (DEVNODE.devserver1) [Thread 25920] (Msg 1/3) BIP2628W: Exception condition detected on input node 'gen.TestLoanOrch.getGetLoanInfo (Implementation).HTTP Asynchronous Response'.
Jul  1 14:50:33 testesb ACE[25140]: IBM App Connect Enterprise v11008 (DEVNODE.devserver1) [Thread 25920] (Msg 2/3) BIP3655S: An HTTPAsyncResponse node with the unique identifier 'loanInfoAsyncCall' encountered an error while processing an inbound response message.
Jul  1 14:50:33 testesb ACE[25140]: IBM App Connect Enterprise v11008 (DEVNODE.devserver1) [Thread 25920] (Msg 3/3) BIP3183E: An HTTPAsyncResponse node did not receive a response from http://10.18.50.64:7004/irf-test-web/api/v1.0.0/party/dfccLoanInfo/100000009266 because the timeout of 30000 milliseconds expired before a response was received.
```

My question is do I have to differentiate request identifier for each request in the loop so that the asynchronous response node will correlate the request/response?

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yasothar - did you find a solution

Comment: Hi Rohan, Yes I had to change my methodology, I used group nodes, please check out which i wrote about, in case if you are interested. https://ayasothar.medium.com/ibm-app-connect-enterprise-ace-group-nodes-ef507517f6d2